# My log file is empty but the server odoo is working

Tags: logging, odoo, ubuntu-20.04, odoo-12

i couldnt find my file log and when i check odoo status i get this error, please help me

```
/odoo.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
since Wed 2021-09-01 16:45:57 UTC; 36min ago

odoo/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-server.conf (code=exited, status=2)
=2)

 Started Odoo.
4541]: Usage: odoo-bin [options]
4541]: odoo-bin: error: The config file '/etc/odoo-server.conf' selected with -c/--config doesn't exist or is not readable, use -s/--save if you want to gen>
 odoo.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
 odoo.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
```

Comment: are you sure that you have the read permissions for that file ?

Comment: The permission error "is right at your face"? Please check the permissions on the config file, which is defined in the service ("init") file.

Comment: hi,thanks for you answers. i resolved it i had problem in my config file in the path